# Debugging - setting breakpoints on lines with no code

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

This is a general (and probably very naive) question about setting and using breakpoints in debugging.  (I happen to be using PhpStorm and Xdebug to debug a php web page, but I think the question may be more general than that).

I've noticed that if I want to evaluate a variable while debugging, I have to set a breakpoint on a line *after* the variable I want to evaluate.  But what if there are no further lines of code in the file?  What is the "best practice" for that situation?  Currently, I'm just adding `echo "";` after my variable line, and breaking on that.  That is working, but surely that's not the right way, is it?

Comment: Can you step over or into the last line?    Is the problem that the debugger stops when it hits the end of the file?

Comment: Ah!  That worked!  I set the breakpoint on the line that contains the variable, then stepped over a few times, and all of the variables filled in.  Thank you for the help.  I realize this is a very newbie question, but the answer is invaluable.

Comment: No problem, stepping is very useful in debuggers.

Answer (score 1):

As Devon pointed out in the comments, the answer is to set the breakpoint *on* the line that contains the variable I wanted, then Step Over a few times to allow the variable to evaluate.